# Resize an installation window

Tags: window-management

I am using a virtual machine to use Ubuntu to download a program. However, the default installation window of the program is too big, the Next button is off the screen.

[image]

I can only make the window bigger but not smaller. I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

If the window is hard-coded to have a minimum size bigger than your screen, then probably there's no easy way to make it smaller.

However, you can access the '**Next**' button by moving the window upwards. To do that press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then click *anywhere* inside the window and drag upwards.

If <kbd>Alt</kbd> doean't work, try <kbd>Super</kbd> (usually the key with Windows logo).